# Why my quad core process cannot give its all?

Tags: windows-7, cpu

I have Firefox with Windows 7. My Firefox always has a problem with Flash. It will make one of the four cores in the processor busy. It is OK if it keeps one core busy, however it will also slow my mouse and keyboard response.

I checked the CPU usage; it was only 35-40% (25% coming from the Flash problem). Why does my mouse and keyboard response slow down if my computer still has 60% unused CPU resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with flash not with your CPU.

Comment: I know, but the key point is that I still have 60% remain, but I have difficult to move my cursor. I need to move my cursor and then stop the FLASH.

Comment: flash is most likely taking up valuable space in some type of memory or process and that is what's preventing you from moving your mouse. Your CPU usage has nothing to do with this.

Comment: "Most likely"? Are you sure, or are you guessing? How do you know it's a problem with Flash, any sources?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling Flash and possibly also Firefox. I'm using FF19 with the latest version of Flash on Win7 x64 and it works well.